# SQL: Join tables excluding duplicates in second table

Tags: sql, join, duplicates, subquery, no-duplicates

I have two tables (Table1 and Table2) that need to be joined.

The column `id` links Table1 and Table2.

- The output table needs to contain all rows in Table1.
- Table2 has duplicates which should not show up in the output table.
- If a duplicate row in Table2 has `NULL` in a column for a given `id`, and if another row in Table2 has a value in this column for the same `id`, then the output table should contain the value instead of `NULL`. (i.e. like in `id` 002 , 003 and 005 in the example below)
- If duplicate rows contain different values for the same column for a given `id`. Any of the values can be taken to the output table. (i.e. like in `id` 001 in the example below)

**Example:**

Table 1:

```
ID     Value1
----   ------
001    Mary
002    Jane
003    Peter
004    Smith
005    Katy
```

Table 2:

```
ID     Value2  Value3
----   ------  ------
001    25      33
001    25      38
001    NULL    33
002    NULL    NULL
002    18      56
003    22      NULL
005    NULL    34
```

I need to join the tables and get the following result:

```
ID     Value1  Value2  Value3
----   ------  ------  ------
001    Mary    25      33
002    Jane    47      88
003    Peter   22      NULL
004    Smith   NULL    NULL
005    Katy    NULL    34
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a885/1/0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.ID, T1.Value1, 
  (
    SELECT ST2.Value2 
    FROM Table2 ST2 
    WHERE T1.ID = ST2.ID
    ORDER BY ST2.Value2
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS Value2, 
  (
    SELECT ST3.Value3 
    FROM Table2 ST3 
    WHERE T1.ID = ST3.ID
    ORDER BY ST3.Value3
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS Value3 
FROM Table1 AS T1
```

Comment: @Linger thanks for the answer. There was something that I have missed. There are NULL values that I need to avoid from the output. What needs to be done to remove these? (updated tables in question)

Comment: **@slayernoah**, I don't know if I follow you.  Do you want records with NULLS to not show up at all?  Or, do you want them to show as `0` instead?

Comment: I have added a few more scenarios that I had missed to the question. Please see this fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e89ea/1). There are duplicate rows in the output table.